# ponteiro não funciona no visual studio

Tags: c, ponteiro

Pessoal minha pergunta é simples porém faz com que eu não consiga trabalhar com ponteiros, a variável 'y' simplesmente não recebe o endereço de x no exemplo abaixo:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

    int *y, x;
    

    printf("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &x);

    y = &x;

    printf("Voce digitou o numero %d\n", y);

    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Obrigado a todos pela a ajuda

Comment: Como `y` é um ponteiro você deve usar: `printf("Voce digitou o numero %d\n", *y);`. Imprimir o conteúdo apontado por `y`.

Comment: Isso mesmo, a literatura que estou lendo estava incorreta nesse ponto, na hora que for printar o conteudo de um ponteiro necessario digitar * antes. Valeu!

Comment: Se a literatura que está utilizando erra em um ponto tão básico acho que é melhor mudar de literatura.

Answer (score -2):

coloca um asterisco antes do y no printf("Voce digitou o numero %d\n", y);